# Visual Composer and User roles Issue

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, multisite, visual-composer

I'm using Visual Composer in wpbakery 5.4.5 version on my Multisite setup .  But only super admin can use the page builder without issue . if non 'super admin' uses the page builder , the page layout will be scrambled . I'm looking forward to hear something helpful

PS: 
I found the cause ofthe issue , when post updates content will changed `[vc_column width="1/2"]` in to `[vc_column width=\"1/2\"]` with slashes . it does not happen for super admin , only when update or create post by Administrator, Editor, Author, Contributor and Subscriber .
now I need to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

log in as network admin(super admin) and in user settings give that plugin priviliges

Comment: I don't want to give super admin privilege to everyone , I want to fix this for user roles Administrator, Editor, Author, Contributor and Subscriber